# Why storing a payroll in XML type field would be good or bad

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, xml, tsql

We have a PAYROLL issues by the client to make it dynamic i.e. to make the whole process computerized.

It includes:

1. Employees
2. Allowances (Scale wise, which could change yearly or monthly or anytime)
3. Incentives
4. Some Allowances based on experience and districts
5. Some allowances are calculated by applying 45% to the basic pay but some are static and can be changed anytime
6. AdHOC reliefs is the main problem: Currently GOVERNMENT is working on the basis of notifications issued in 2008, 2014, 2015 but coming years might not be the same i.e. revised policy.

hunhhhhhh...... so the problem is that we can not find the pattern to make it dynamic or even static because it cannot be so we came up with the idea of uploading the excel sheet to the system which contains all the data which they put on daily basis and we will save that Excel sheet in XML datatype column in sql table. So in future if we are asked to provide employee wise report or salary increment or allowances wise report the we would be able to generate data from the XML datatype.

So is it possible or feasible to do ?

We are using asp.net(C#) and sql server 2014.

Comment: Are you having trouble with the 'changing policy' part, which makes hard-coding rules infeasible? Is that why you are looking at Excel - because of its formula system? Should your client be able to update the rules of their payroll system themselves or is that a service that your company will provide?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet yes because existing formulae and columns are subject to change. They can change it according to government's newly implemented rules

Comment: and yes they change the rules themselves, and asking us just to provide them Payroll management system which would transform the daily work into computer

Comment: If your client is used to working with Excel anyway then building a custom web-interface and formula system is perhaps not very economic. But Excel is already a computer program - so what is there to 'transform into a computer'? What is the added value of your payroll program on top of using Excel? What exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

The challenge you face is that payroll calculation is complex and subject to changing rules. You do **not** solve this problem by uploading excel sheets or storing data as XML - rather it will just add an additional layer of complexity and fragility.

Comment: so what we can do in this case ?

Comment: @Quoran: What exactly is the problem that you need help solving? Is it how to add new calculations in the future? You need to be more specific with the question.

Comment: @Jaccques: the way they add columns and change existing calculation formulae.

Comment: @Quoran: Typically calculations would be represented in code (which will have to be updated every time a new formula is added), but if they very frequently are changed and updated it might make sense to represented as rules in the database. But if if calculations are only added once a year as the question suggest, it is probably easiest to represent it in code.